# IMPORTAR CSV a MYSQL con LOAD DATA INFILE

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, csv

Cómo puedo estructurar mi query para importar un csv a mi base de datos utilizando LOAD DATA INFILE. El tema aquí es que sólo requiero ciertas columnas, no todo el archivo.

Mi tabla lleva las columnas siguientes:

[image: columnas de la tabla]

El cómo estoy haciendo el query es de la siguiente forma:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'captura.csv'
INTO TABLE ejemplo (fechainicio, fechafin, magna, premium,diesel)
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

Espero alguien que sepa cómo guardar sólo ciertas columnas de mi archivo csv pueda apoyarme en hacerme ver qué estoy haciendo mal. ¡Muchas gracias!

el archivo csv lleva las siguientes columnas:

[image: tabla en bd]

Answer (score 0):

Justo es algo que podrias hacer con variables.

Te dejo una script de ayuda:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'captura.csv'
INTO TABLE ejemplo (fechainicio, fechafin, magna, premium,diesel)
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
IGNORE 1 LINES
(
                @fechainicio,
                @fechafin,
                @magna,
                @premium,
                @diesel
            )
            SET

                `fechainicio` = @fechainicio,
                `fechafin` = @fechafin,
                `magna` = @magna,
                `premium` = @premium,
                `diesel` = @diesel
```

El orden de tus columnas en el csv debe ser el mismo orden en el que lo quieras guardar en tu base de datos.